# Why the leverage is the diagonal elements of the Hat matrix?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, linear-model, matrix

Why the leverage is the diagonal elements of the Hat matrix? I know the meaning of leverage, just do not know the relation with the formula. Any proof? Or intuitive explanation?